# finding stationary solution of a continuous time markov chain.

Tags: probability-distributions, systems-of-equations, markov-chains, stationary-point, infinite-matrices

With a certain rate $R$ balls fall into a box. There is no limit to the number of balls the box can hold, but each ball has a rate $\gamma$ to leave the box and when two balls hit each other they leave both the box. The probability that two balls hit each other is $\beta$.

One can build a markov chain to describe this process. The rate matrix of this problem is the following pentadiagonal matrix:

$$
P = 
\begin{pmatrix}
    -R & R & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 & \dots \\
    w_{1} & q_1 & R & 0 & \dots & \vdots & \dots \\
    v_2 & w_{2} & q_2 & R & \dots & 0 & \dots \\
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & R & \dots \\
    0 & \dots & 0 & v_i & w_{i} &  q_i & \dots \\
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots &  \vdots & \vdots & \ddots\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
where $$\begin{cases}
v_i=\beta i (i-1) \\
w_i=\gamma i \\
q_i = -R-v_i-w_i
\end{cases}
$$

To find the stationary state I have to solve:
$$ \bar{x}P = 0 $$
that corresponds to this system:

\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
-R x_0 + w_1 x_1 + v_2 x_2 = 0 \\
R x_0 -(v_1 + w_1 + R) x_1 + w_2 x_2 + v_3 x_3 = 0\\
\vdots \\
R x_{i-1} -(v_i + w_i + R) x_i + w_{i+1} x_{i+1} + v_{i+2} x_{i+2} = 0\\
\vdots \\
\end{cases}
\label{system_stat_stat}
\end{equation}

there exist a closed (not recursive) analytical solution of it? if yes, how can I get it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It turns out that the probability generating function of $\bar{x}=(x_0, x_1, x_2, \ldots)$, namely $f(z)=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}x_i z^i$, solves the differential equation $$\beta(z+1)f''(z)+\gamma f'(z)-Rf(z)=0,$$ hence it is given by $$f(z)=\frac{{}_0 F_1\left(;\frac{\gamma}{\beta};\frac{R}{\beta}(z+1)\right)}{{}_0 F_1\left(;\frac{\gamma}{\beta};\frac{2R}{\beta}\right)},$$ where ${}_0 F_1(;b;z)$ is the [generalized hypergeometric function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_hypergeometric_function).